# Increment label values according the number of tables

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count the tables in a foreach loop and put the value in a label.

How I can do that?

```
public void FillSchema(List<SchemaPermis> PermisList)
{
    foreach (SchemaPermis item in PermisList)
    {
        bindingSource1.Add(item);
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < PermisList.Count; ++i)
            if (PermisList.Count > 0)
                i = i + 1;

        xrLabel1.Text = String.Format("Permis: {0}", i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should work..what is the problem?

Comment: I don't see how this code should work at all. `i` is incremented in the for loop and also conditionally. Why use a loop to count items in a list that has a `Count` property?

Answer (score 2):

There are some incoherent things in your exemple...

Firstly, you want to put the result in one Label, but in your foreach you try to put multiple values one after one in the Label...

But I think you should do this:

```
public int TableCount { get; private set; }
```

For a Label with the number of tables:

In your ViewModel:

```
TableCount = 0;
foreach (var schema in PermisList)
{
   TableCount += schema.Count;
}
If (PropertyChanged != null)
     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TableCount"));
```

In your Xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding TableCount}"/>
```